# Adding key:value pair to JSON using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have an Object initially like the following

```
var data={title: "Italy"}
```

I want t check few conditions and then add to the data whoch met the condoitions :

```
if(condition1)
     //output will be data={title: "Italy",id1: somecaluatedvalue}
if(condition2)
     /*output will be data={title: "Italy",id1: somecaluatedvalue,id2: somevalue} 
      if condition1 was also true or data={title: "Italy",id1=2: somecaluatedvalue} if 
      condition1 was false */
```

It will continue in this way inside a loop.
How can i do this in javascript?

Comment: You don't have JSON. You have JS object initializers.

Comment: `I have a JSON ` no you don't. You have an object literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a JSON

No you don't, you have an object literal.

To set properties on a Javascript object you can do this:

```
data.id1 = somevalue;
```

or this:

```
data["id1"] = somevalue;
```

The second is particularly useful when you need to dynamically generate property name, which seems to something you are alluding to. So you could do something like this:

```
for (var i=0; i < arrayOfConditions.length; i++) {
    if (arrayOfConditions[i]) {
        data["id" + i] = somevalue;
    }
}
```

And if you *do* need JSON at the end, you can just do:

```
var myJson = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Comment: Thanks. That helps. If i add quation to the key will it be JSON?

Comment: @MdJohirulIslam: No. It'll still be an object. JSON is a string.